# Use Zend_Queue without Zend Server

Tags: zend-framework, zend-server, zend-queue

Is it possible to use Zend Queue without to have Zend Server installed on a server ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean Zend_Queue class from Zend Framework, then sure - you can download ZF from http://framework.zend.com/ and use it independently.

If you mean Zend Job Queue, then no, it's part of Zend Server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , Zend_queue is a part of zend_framework, with  a driver for Zend_server but also a driver  to memcachedQ, or  over Zend_Db  or many other system.